# What is the meaning of this Azure Batch Autoscale formula?

Tags: azure, formula

Here's an example from Azure Document. However, i found it pretty confusing.

```
startingNumberOfVMs = 1;
maxNumberofVMs = 25;
pendingTaskSamplePercent = $PendingTasks.GetSamplePercent(180 * TimeInterval_Second);
pendingTaskSamples = pendingTaskSamplePercent < 70 ? startingNumberOfVMs : avg($PendingTasks.GetSample(180 * TimeInterval_Second));
$TargetDedicatedNodes=min(maxNumberofVMs, pendingTaskSamples);
```

My take on this formula is:

```
- We start with 1 VM
- The maximum VM we can reach to is 25
- PendingTasks = the number of running VM. Let say 10 VMs are running.
- In last 180 seconds, if the percent of pending task < 70% (that means < 3 VM running?) then ...
```

Someone please explain this in details since i don't have any experiences with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Automatic scaling formulas:

> The Batch service uses your formula to determine the target number of
>   compute nodes in the pool for the next interval of processing.

**So the example means:**

The Batch pool starts with 1 node, and the max number of nodes is 25. It means you can only have 25 nodes at most.

And in the next interval of processing, if the formula finds the average number of pending tasks in the last 180 seconds less than 70 (you can change this number as you wish according to your environment), it means the pending tasks are not too many and the work is not too heavy. So the target node is still 1 and need not grow. But if the average number is more than 70, the target nodes need to autoscale. The formula ensures that the target number of dedicated nodes never exceeds 25 VMs. So

```
$TargetDedicatedNodes=min(maxNumberofVMs, pendingTaskSamples)
```

As new tasks are submitted, the pool automatically grows. As tasks complete, VMs become free one by one and the autoscaling formula shrinks the pool.

That's my understanding of the Batch Autoscale. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Charles, thank you for your answer. 
I'm a little lost at this line. 

pendingTaskSamples = pendingTaskSamplePercent < 70 ? startingNumberOfVMs : avg($PendingTasks.GetSample(180 * TimeInterval_Second)); 

70% here means 70% of 25 nodes, right?

Comment: No, it not mean 70% of 25 nodes. I think it means a percent of the task samples. You can take a look at [Samples, sample percentage, and the GetSample() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-automatic-scaling#samples-sample-percentage-and-the-getsample-method).

Answer (score 1):

The function wants to set as a target a number of nodes equal to the average number of pending tasks (pending = running + queued) in the last 180 seconds. Basically, it wants to have approximately one node per task.

However, it will only do so if there is enough data to make a meaningful decision. Sample collection does not always succeed.

If, during the last 180 seconds, for whatever reason, not enough samples of the number of pending tasks were collected (specifically, less than 70%), then we default to 1 node.